# How to scale with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, memcached, scalability, sidekiq

I would like to prepare a rails application to be scalable. Some features of this app is to connect to some APIs & send emails, plus I'm using PostgreSQL & it's on Heroku.

Now that code is clean, I would like to use caches and any technique that will help the app to scale.

Should I use Redis or Memcached ? It's a little obscur to me and I've seen similar questions on StackOverflow but here I would like to know which one I should use only for scaling purpose.

Also I was thinking to use Sidekiq to process some jobs. Is it going to conflict with Memcached/Redis ? Also, in wich case should I use it ?

Any other things I should think of in terms of scalability ?

Many thanks

Comment: You also have to scale in infrastructure (servers). Preferably vertical scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Redis is a very good choice for caching, it has similar performances to memcached (redis is slightly faster) and it takes few minutes to configure it that way.

If possibile I would suggest agains using the same redis instance to store both cache and message store.

If you really need to do that make sure you configure redis with volatile-lru max memory policy and that you always set your cache with a TTL; this way when redis runs out of memory cache keys will be evicted.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq requires Redis as its message store.  So you will need to have a Redis instance or use a Redis service if you want to use Sidekiq.  Sidekiq is great, btw.

You can use either Memcached or Redis as your cache store.  For caching I'd probably use Memcached as the cache cleaning behavior is better.  In Rails in general, and in Rails 4 apps in particular, one rarely explicit expires an item from cache or sets an explicit expiration time.  Instead one depends on updates to the cache_key, which means the cached item isn't actually deleted from the store.  Memcached handles this pretty well, by evicting the least recently used items when it hits memory limits.

That all said, scaling is a lot more than picking a few components.  You'll have to do a fair amount of planning, identify bottlenecks as the app develops, and scale CPU/memory/disk by increasing servers as needed.

Comment: wrong! redis has max memory eviction too and it works much better better than the one in memcached (http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/13506116892/memcached-internals-memory-allocation-eviction)

Answer (score 0):

You must look at the two cool features of Redis that are yet to come in near future

**Redis Cluster:**

- http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec
- http://redis.io/presentation/Redis_Cluster.pdf

**Redis Sentinel: (Highly Available)**

- http://redis.io/topics/sentinel
- http://redis.io/topics/sentinel-spec

Also these features will yield a great help in scaling redis,
In case of memcached these features are missing, also as far as active development is concerned redis community is fare more vibrant.